# Retrieve Resource Values Programmatically in asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to get strings from my App_resource programmatically because I get from the DB a keyword with the name of the string in the app_resource mlbRes.

I have a stored procedure that indicates what the user should do next, sending a string that corresponds to a string in my app_resources file. I can do it with a switch, but that will only complicate my code.

As you can see in the following screenshot, I've tried different approaches, but none worked so far.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A4uy0.png)

Can anyone point me out what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: string value= Resources.mlbRes.ResourceManager.GetString("StringName"); should work. Here mlbRes is your resource filename

Comment: Hello Shetty, Thank you. It works: string value = mlbRes.ResourceManager.GetString(t.show);

Comment: added my answer. Accept it, if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Use this Syntax Here mlbRes is your resource file name

```
string value= Resources.mlbRes.ResourceManager.GetString("StringName");
```